# Error messge: Generation has thrown an exception: list index out of range when wanting to generate rig

Tags: rigging, rigify

i know this question was asked before but there was never an answer. I used a human meta-rig and wanted to use generate rig. But no mater what I do the error message:

Generation has thrown an exception: list index out of range 
apears.

Does anyone know how to fix the issue?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess: you tried to partially delete the face.
Unfortunately you can't selectively delete parts of the face (as of 2.82a, later versions may provide more flexibility). 
Either keep the whole face or delete all bones that belong to it.

Some info may be found here:
https://developer.blender.org/T53842

Comment: You are right, the changes to the meta-rig were the problem. I think that if you delete any bones it wont work. I used a default rig and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: You can delete some bones but you have to understand the Rig Types. That will allow you to delete or add any features you want.

Comment: I just retoped the mesh with instantMeshes to around 100k to make sure the messy topology wasnt an issue. What makes me wonder: ctrl-P doesnt bring up "Automatic weight" option. I used the object meue ->parenting for that

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem when I joined multiple armatures together because of a different error. All I had to do was to replace that merged armature with a new one where all of the bones came from the same armature.

Answer (score 0):

As I set the original python output and debug, in my situation, looks likes there was an addtional bone within the leg(maybe other limb) bone (there were "lower leg" and "iK" parent to "upper bone")