# Error: "Exception: List Index Out Of Range" every time I press generate rig

Tags: error, rigify

I just started using blender a few weeks ago. This is my first time creating something on my own so I don't know what's going on. It still generates the rig, just that it doesn't line up with the bones and model. Here's the file in case anyone knows what's wrong with it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PXNtEJNSAVie8IrlVcftcarXLhc-_O3U/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Rigify is not really designed for rigging robots. It's designed to be used with the supplied armatures although it is possible to modify them somewhat. You should watch a tutorial on robot rigging. There are lots around. One thing I did notice is that the scale hasn't been applied to any of your objects. Select all the parts and use Ctrl-S > Scale in Object mode. Their origin is also offset from the world origin in the X position which wouldn't help when you're trying to rig your model. Again select them all and use the Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor menu.

Comment: See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178060/error-messge-a-has-thrown-an-exception-list-index-out-of-range-when-w?rq=1 for the actual error that you're seeing.

Comment: Hello, Brandon, welcome to BSE. The commentary and link  do suggest it's fair to close this as a duplicate. If the linked answer isn't working for you, please edit this post to explain why. The we can re-open, armed with a bit more info that will help us to help you.